# Downloading software for Outdated Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation, software-updates

Supposedly I have an outdated Linux Mint edition whose corresponding Ubuntu version has been discontinued i.e. it has reached its end-of-life. How will I download software for the same outdated Mint?

I am asking this question specifically because I've used an outdated Ubuntu earlier and it needed a change of repositories reference, something like modifying source.list from 'archive.ubuntu.com' to 'old-release.ubuntu.com'.

Do Mint have something of their own servers where the old/outdated softwares are reserved?
or,
A similar procedure is needed?

I want to use an old machine of mine for the very basic purpose of eg. managing data on disk (movies, music, videos), PDF and other document reading, some very basic browsing (although it will be prone to security breaches & attacks, I understand) i.e. security patches are of least concern for me but software might be required further.

PS : I am asking this because I don't often update my system and doesn't know that at what point of time (few years later or so) I would just require a piece of software without complete updation of OS.

Comment: You are aware of the two main problems of using an operating system after its end of life: security and problems to upgrade or install new program packages. I am more familiar with Ubuntu than Mint, but you can try the same method as with the Ubuntu repositories. But I suggest that you make a fresh installation of the newest LTS version (Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS and the corresponding Mint version, which I think is 19.1, and that you repeat these fresh installations in August or September every even year for Ubuntu and some month later for Mint.

Comment: In an old computer it is a good idea to install an Ubuntu community flavour with a lighter diesktop environment than standard Ubuntu, for example Lubuntu, Ubuntu Budgie, Ubimtu MATE or Xubuntu. I think that the XFCE flavour of Mint has the lightest footprint (but you may prefer another desktop environment).